# Docker: вызов sendmail с хоста

Tags: docker, sendmail

На хосте настроен exim4 на 25-м порту. Есть скрипт, который отправляет почту через /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i ...

Как сделать, чтобы аналогичный скрипт, помещённый в контейнер мог отправлять почту, через хостовый exim?

Пока мысли только в сторону того, чтобы либо запускать с докера скрипт на хосте (но, как я понимаю, это просто так не сделать) или пробросить 25-й порт внутрь, но я умею только из контейнера наружу )

Comment: Поставить и настроить в докере msmtp-mta или ssmtp? Они умеют эмулировать sendmail

Comment: по поводу доступа к хосту из контейнера возможно поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container#:~:text=To%20access%20host%20machine%20from,using%20it%20to%20anything%20else.&text=Then%20make%20sure%20that%20you,0.0%20.

Comment: Вот тут есть по поводу доступа к хосту https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1277274/docker-compose-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0/1277753