# Docker volume как из контейнера использовать скрипты на хосте

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Не могу разобраться как из докер-контейнера выполнить скрипт который лежит на хосте?

Расклад такой, имеет Raspberry-pi (далее хост), на хосте есть файл get_data.py который собирает данные с камеры и датчиков температуры подключенных к хосту. Скрипт собрав данные возвращает DTO. Локально все работает как надо, но как мне вызвать скрипт get_data.py из докер-контейнера???

Буду очень признателен за пример dockerfile.

PS docker-compose.yml - пока не рассматриваю.

Comment: Камера и датчики как подключены? По USB? Тут часть проблемы в том, чтоб дать доступ программе из докера к устройствам на хосте.

Comment: Камера и датчики на пинах. Все библиотеки и скрипты котрые собирают данные лежат локально, я представляю себе такую картину: в контейнере есть скрипт который запускает скрипты что лежат на хосте и те в свою очередь передают результат свое работы обратно в скрипт который в контейнере. И получается что обращение к железу происходит не из докера. Но вот как это организовать не совсем понимаю (

Comment: Да вообще-то можно и к пинам доступ в докер прокинуть https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234752/2231972, а если все же работа с пинами будет на хосте, то сделать запуск по требованию особо не сделаешь (точнее не смысла), т.к. нужен процесс, который будет ждать, когда попросят запустить.  Проще уже чтоб само это приложение по запросу (например, http запросу) опрашивало датчики и отдавало данные. Или как вариант постоянно читать и складывать в хранилище в докере. Тут только вопрос возникает, зачем в этой конфигурации докер?

Comment: Малинка один из микросервисов большого проекта, и одно из основных требований - докер. В целом замысел именно такой, сервер (Джанго) отправляет http запрос на малинку и та отдает json или DTO с данными от датчиков и камеры.

Comment: Тогда просто на raspberry pi запустите сервер, не обязательно django. На fastapi будет проще/ Вот [пример](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/), в методе root вызывайте себе GPIO и возвращайте результат. И вызывайте этот сервис из докера используя хотя бы reverse ssh tunnel https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277753/218971

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Спасибо большое за наводку ) Ты не мог бы ответить на вопрос своим комментарием выше, что бы я его отметил как решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение задачи нашел **[тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163955/how-to-run-shell-script-on-host-from-docker-container)** Как и следовало ожидать есть два пути решения поставленной задачи, [именованные туннели](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/linux_parallel/node17.html) или простой [http сервер](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)  на хосте который слушает определенный порт. Вариант с сервером долее безопасный.